# mongo store map as second class,and how to find when i donot known the key

Tags: mongodb

I hava a data like this. how to find filed "info1" value when I donot known the port

```
{
    "ip":"1.1.1.1",
    "name":"myName",
    "portInfo":{
        "80":{
            "info1":"xxx",
            "info2":"xxx"
        },
        "81":{
            "info1":"xxx",
            "info2":"xxx"
        }
    }
}
```

I need the result like this. convert the Map into Arry，with parent Fields

```
[ { "ip": "1.1.1.1", "name": "myName", "info1": "xxx", "info2": "xxx" },
  { "ip": "1.1.1.1", "name": "myName", "info1": "xxx", "info2": "xxx" } ]
```

Comment: How does your required o/p look like & any particular input ?

Comment: I need the result like this. 
convert the Map into Arry，with parent Fields
[
 {
  "ip": "1.1.1.1",
  "name": "myName",
  "info1": "xxx",
  "info2": "xxx"
},
 {
 "ip": "1.1.1.1",
 "name": "myName",
  "info1": "xxx",
  "info2": "xxx"
  }
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$objectToArray`

```
db.getCollection('Test05').aggregate([
{ $project: { "ip":1, "name":1, portInfo: { $objectToArray: "$portInfo" } } }, 
{ $unwind:"$portInfo"},
{ $project: {_id:0,
    "ip":1,
    "name":1,
    "info1": "$portInfo.v.info1",
    "info2": "$portInfo.v.info2",
    } }
])
```

Result:

```
{
    "ip" : "1.1.1.1",
    "name" : "myName",
    "info1" : "xxx",
    "info2" : "xxx"
},    
{
    "ip" : "1.1.1.1",
    "name" : "myName",
    "info1" : "xxx",
    "info2" : "xxx"
}
```

Comment: it works, but how can I add parent fields to the result; like this    
 [
   {
 "ip": "1.1.1.1",
 "name": "myName",
 "info1": "xxx",
 "info2": "xxx"
 },
{
  "ip": "1.1.1.1",
  "name": "myName",
  "info1": "xxx",
  "info2": "xxx"
 }
]

Comment: you can add any field using the $project. i made an update.